# Dart extension functions not found

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

I have a project on flutter and I want to use extension methods there very much.
I've upgraded `pubspec.yaml` file to use `sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"`.
I create a file `list_extensions.dart` with content

```dart
import 'dart:math';

extension ListExtension<T> on List<T> {

  T randomElement() => this.elementAt(Random().nextInt(this.length));

}
```

When I try to use this extension method in other files like this

```dart
String getRandomText(List<String> texts) => texts.randomElement();
```

I see a compiler error with text: `The method 'randomElement' isn't defined for the class 'List'`.

But when I try to use this extension method inside `list_extensions.dart` file - compiler is ok with that.

The thing is that my other project can found all extension methods that I declare.

`flutter doctor` says:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.17-pre.74, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A603, locale en-RU)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

`flutter --version` says:

```
Flutter 1.10.17-pre.74 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision bcc93bca23 (6 days ago) • 2019-11-13 11:31:20 -0800
Engine • revision 31cd2dfca2
Tools • Dart 2.7.0
```

What can I do to force the compiler to see my extension methods?

Comment: The file where the extension is defined must be imported

Comment: If I add import manually - I really can use extension methods that I declared. Thanks for the advice. But I thought that extension methods should be recognised by IDE as methods for a class that I extend. I want to use autocomplete. Will it be working as I expect at least in the near future?

Comment: I'm using Dart 2.6.1 and VS Code. When I import my file that contains the extension methods, Intellisense works as it should.

Comment: I came to flutter and dart from Android and Kotlin and it seems very practical to me that extension methods should be available everywhere in your project. Otherwise, I should be aware of what extensions have been declared for what classes everywhere in the app. Static functions can be found but not extension methods? Seems illogical to me.

Comment: The thing about extension methods is that they can be defined anywhere, including external packages. What if one package defines an extension method for a native Dart type and another package defines an extension method with the same name but different behavior? If extension methods were available globally by default, this would cause an irreconcilable conflict. By having to import the extension method file, you are defining when you want to use the extension method or not, and which one you want to use when there are conflicting ones.

Comment: Also, outside of the built-in types and methods, nothing in Dart can be made implicitly global. Any time you want to use code that was written outside of the file you have opened, you need to import it. Why should extension methods be any different?

Comment: Probably I was not clear about what behaviour I expect. I do not want to use extension methods without importing them. I totally agree that this would be inappropriate. I just want an IDE to be able to see them and suggest me to import them while I'm typing their names - simple auto-completion with auto-importing.

Comment: I'm not sure that makes much sense either. The extension would have to parse every single source file in every single location whether it's imported or not just to see if there are any extension types in it. It's different than auto importing things like types and global constants, since the auto importer would have to keep track of every type _as well as every other class that references it_. Of course, this also comes down to the fact that Dart just barely got support for extension methods, so expecting the extension to already have robust support for it is a bit unreasonable.

Comment: I understand that support is just being added, but I want to leave my two cents on the matter. One huge benefit of extension functions over util functions is that they are suggested in auto-complete. If I need to know where each extension function is, might as well use Utils. In fact, it's probably easier to use util classes with suggestions and auto-import than it is to remember and manually type import lines.

Answer (score 36):

It was not your case, but for me, it worked after updating the Android Studio, Flutter plugin and Dart plugin.
Maybe it'll help someone else.

Version that `extension` methods are working:

- Android Studio 3.6.2
- Flutter Plugin 192.7761
- Dart Plugin 45.1.1

And another important point is that `extension` must be named. If it's not named it can't be used in other files:

Private `extension`:

```dart
extension on Banana {
  // ...
}
```

Public `extension`:

```dart
extension BananaExtension on Banana {
  // ...
}
```

I found it in a comment on Dart `extension` announcement [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3j0OSfT9ZI)

Comment: Looks like this broke in 3.6.3 :(

Comment: The numbers are swapped for dart and flutter.

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods were introduced in Dart 2.7, so you can change your sdk version: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: Yeah, I declared it from the beginning. But surely it can help someone

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone in the future I had an issue with using extensions on `final` rather than the class name. I had:

```dart
extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool isFuture() {
    ...
  }
}

final time = 'some time of day';
if (time.isFuture()) {
...
}
```

This was throwing an error, to solve it I needed to do:

```dart
final String time = 'some time of day';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the sdk version in pubspec.yaml to 2.6

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my extension and i have created this extension inside **string_extension.dart**

```
extension EmailValidator on String {
  bool isValidEmail() {
    return RegExp(
            r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}
```

So in order to make this extension work you just need to import this extension_file
like

```
import 'package:projectname/extensions/string_extension.dart';
```

and then

```
final String email = 'test@gmail.com';
if(email.isValidEmail()){
}
```